# html increase top margins in a div

Tags: html, css

I want the distance from the display to the buttons in the second calculator to be 100px but I don't know how to do that.

This is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design2.css" >
    <title>Calculator Italy</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="skyblue">
    <form>
        <div id="italyCalc">
            <input type="text" id="display" disabled><br>

            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('1')" value="1" >
            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('2')" value="2" >
            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('3')" value="3" >
            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('+')" value="+" ><br>

            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('4')" value="4" >
            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('5')" value="5" >
            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('6')" value="6" >
            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="deleteLast()" value="<--" ><br>

            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('7')" value="7" >
            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('8')" value="8" >
            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('9')" value="9" >

            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('.')" value="." ><br>
            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('0')" value="0" >
            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('-')" value="-" >
            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('*')" value="*" >
            <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('/')" value="/" ><br>

            <input type="button" id="itemBig" onclick="adding('C')" value="C" >
            <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="power('2')" value="X^2" >
            <input type="button" id="itemBig" onclick="returnResult()" value="=" >

        </div>
        <div id="italyCalc2">
            <input type="text" id="display2" disabled><br>


            <input type="button" id="item" onclick="adding2('1')" value="1" >
            <input type="button" id="item" onclick="adding2('2')" value="2" >
            <input type="button" id="item" onclick="adding2('3')" value="3" >
            <input type="button" id="item" onclick="adding2('+')" value="+" >
            <input type="button" id="item" onclick="power3('3')" value="X^3" ><br>

            <input type="button" id="item" onclick="adding2('4')" value="4" >
            <input type="button" id="item" onclick="adding2('5')" value="5" >
            <input type="button" id="item" onclick="adding2('6')" value="6" >
            <input type="button" id="item" onclick="deleteLast2()" value="<--" >
            <input type="button" id="item" onclick="sin2()" value="sin" ><br>

            <input type="button" id="item" onclick="adding2('7')" value="7" >
            <input type="button" id="item" onclick="adding2('8')" value="8" >
            <input type="button" id="item" onclick="adding2('9')" value="9" >

            <input type="button" id="item" onclick="adding2('.')" value="." >
            <input type="button" id="item" onclick="cos2()" value="cos" ><br>
            <input type="button" id="item" onclick="adding2('0')" value="0" >
            <input type="button" id="item" onclick="adding2('-')" value="-" >
            <input type="button" id="item" onclick="adding2('*')" value="*" >
            <input type="button" id="item" onclick="adding2('/')" value="/" >
            <input type="button" id="item" onclick="root2('2')" value="sqrt" ><br>

            <input type="button" id="itemBig" onclick="adding2('C')" value="C" >
            <input type="button" id="itemBig" onclick="returnResult2()" value="=" >

        </div>
    </form>
<script src="logic2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is part of my css code:

```
#italyCalc2
{
    height: 500px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 3px solid green;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px green;
    background-image: url("https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.M4cfd6650aaff3feadc8bed590687b6b7H0&pid=15.1&P=0&w=274&h=172");
    margin: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    float:left;

}

#display2
{
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px red;
    width: 260px;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: right;
    font: 20px bold;
    color: red;
}

#item
{
    width: 41px;
    height: 41px;
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 31px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px white;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

In other words I want to see the display and 100px below the buttons without modifying the distance from one button to another.

How can I do that?

Comment: just a note: IDs should only be used *once* in a document (you have a lot of 'item', 'item1'  and 'item2'  IDs.) If you want to apply the same styling to them, use classes, but not IDs.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, just add that margin-bottom to `#display2` and make it a block element:

```
#display2 {
  display: block:
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px red;
  width: 260px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: right;
  font: 20px bold;
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a margin-top to your buttons, but you should wrap them in a div.

```css
#italyCalc2 {
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 3px solid green;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px green;
  background-image: url("https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.M4cfd6650aaff3feadc8bed590687b6b7H0&pid=15.1&P=0&w=274&h=172");
  margin: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

#display2 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  //margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px red;
  width: 260px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: right;
  font: 20px bold;
  color: red;
}

#item {
  width: 41px;
  height: 41px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 31px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px white;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.buttons {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="skyblue">
  <form>
    <div id="italyCalc">
      <input type="text" id="display" disabled>
      <br>



      <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('1')" value="1">
      <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('2')" value="2">
      <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('3')" value="3">
      <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('+')" value="+">
      <br>

      <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('4')" value="4">
      <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('5')" value="5">
      <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('6')" value="6">
      <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="deleteLast()" value="<--">
      <br>

      <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('7')" value="7">
      <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('8')" value="8">
      <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('9')" value="9">

      <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="adding('.')" value=".">
      <br>
      <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('0')" value="0">
      <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('-')" value="-">
      <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('*')" value="*">
      <input type="button" id="item2" onclick="adding('/')" value="/">
      <br>

      <input type="button" id="itemBig" onclick="adding('C')" value="C">
      <input type="button" id="item1" onclick="power('2')" value="X^2">
      <input type="button" id="itemBig" onclick="returnResult()" value="=">

    </div>
    <div id="italyCalc2">
      <input type="text" id="display2" disabled>
      <br>

      <div class="buttons">
        <input type="button" id="item" onclick="adding2('1')" value="1">
        <input type="button" id="item" onclick="adding2('2')" value="2">
        <input type="button" id="item" onclick="adding2('3')" value="3">
        <input type="button" id="item" onclick="adding2('+')" value="+">
        <input type="button" id="item" onclick="power3('3')" value="X^3">
        <br>

        <input type="button" id="item" onclick="adding2('4')" value="4">
        <input type="button" id="item" onclick="adding2('5')" value="5">
        <input type="button" id="item" onclick="adding2('6')" value="6">
        <input type="button" id="item" onclick="deleteLast2()" value="<--">
        <input type="button" id="item" onclick="sin2()" value="sin">
        <br>

        <input type="button" id="item" onclick="adding2('7')" value="7">
        <input type="button" id="item" onclick="adding2('8')" value="8">
        <input type="button" id="item" onclick="adding2('9')" value="9">

        <input type="button" id="item" onclick="adding2('.')" value=".">
        <input type="button" id="item" onclick="cos2()" value="cos">
        <br>
        <input type="button" id="item" onclick="adding2('0')" value="0">
        <input type="button" id="item" onclick="adding2('-')" value="-">
        <input type="button" id="item" onclick="adding2('*')" value="*">
        <input type="button" id="item" onclick="adding2('/')" value="/">
        <input type="button" id="item" onclick="root2('2')" value="sqrt">
        <br>

        <input type="button" id="itemBig" onclick="adding2('C')" value="C">
        <input type="button" id="itemBig" onclick="returnResult2()" value="=">

      </div>

    </div>
  </form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ygw062pe/